# C# NEST query does not print out data correctly

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm stuck at a problem, apparently I might have misunderstood something, but here is the problem.

I've got some testdata in a database, but when I run this:

Connection to elastic

```
  private string uri = "http://localhost:9200/";
  private string testindex = "testconnectiones";

  private static ElasticClient GetClient(string testindex, string uri)
    {
        var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri(uri));
        var connectionSettings =
            new ConnectionSettings(pool, sourceSerializer: JsonNetSerializer.Default).DefaultIndex(testindex);

        return new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);
    }
```

Then

```
 public void TestCreateIndexBaseOnOrderId1() 
 {
     var client = GetClient(testindex, uri);
     var searchResponse = client.Search<TestLogs>(s => s
            .AllTypes()
            .From(0)
            .Size(1000)
            .Analyzer("standard")
            .Query(q => q
                .Match(m => m
                    .Field(f => f.OrderID)
                    .Query("")

                )
            )
        );

     var eventTestArray = searchResponse.Documents.Select(x => new {x.OrderID }).ToArray();
     Console.WriteLine("searchResponse.Documents.Count: " + searchResponse.Documents.Count());

     var i = 0;
     var j = 0;
     foreach (var s in eventTestArray)
     {
         Console.WriteLine($"{i}:    " + s);
         i++;
     }

     Assert.AreNotEqual(eventTestArray, null);
 }
```

the output is only:

`searchResponse.Documents.Count: 0.`

There should be 10 orders in the search response.

I just wonder if I've misunderstood something.

The data in the database looks for example like this

```
{
  "_index": "testconnectiones",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
     "OrderId": 1,
     "Event": "CreateOrder"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have in your testdata some OrderID equals ""? It seems to me that is that that you are querying with
`.Field(f => f.OrderID).Query("")`

see [this](https://www.devbridge.com/articles/getting-started-with-elastic-using-net-nest-library-part-three/#)

Comment: @RuiFernandes in the json format looks like this                                                    {
  "_index": "testconnectiones",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "OrderId": 1,
    "Event": "CreateOrder"
  }
}

Comment: Then try to do something like
`.Field(f => f.OrderID).Query("1")` or `.Field(f => f.OrderID).Query(1)`

Answer (score 0):

When using the type `TestLogs`, how does the client know to target `testconnectiones` index?

There are a few things to consider:

1. Ensuring that `testconnectiones` index is queried
2. Ensuring that `f => f.OrderID` will serialize to a string value to target a field that exists for the type and index in Elasticsearch. By default, NEST camel cases property names when serializing
3. Ensuring that the query has an input so that it is not considered "conditionless", or [using `.Verbatim()`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/verbatim-and-strict-query-usage.html) to serialize the query exactly as is
4. [Ensuring that indexed documents are available for search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/near-real-time.html)

Comment: 1. testconnectiones is queried, its probably the serialize that  is the  problem that        2.f => f.OrderID issue is still the same. while using f => f.OrderID).Query("") i gather all data. f => f.OrderID).Query("OrderId 1") or just simply "1" does not work.

Answer (score 0):

A part of the problem was now solved went by.

```
QueryContainer query = new TermQuery()
        {
            Field = "OrderId",
            Value = "1"
        };
        var searchRequest = new SearchRequest(index: "testindex")
        {
            Query = query
        };
        var searchResult = client.Search<TestLogs>(searchRequest);
  foreach (var s in orderIdArray)
        {

            Console.WriteLine($"{i}:    OrderId:" + s.OrderID + " Event: " + s.Event + " Time: " + s.TimeStamp);
            i++;
        }
```

Now is the problem only that if i change

```
 QueryContainer query = new TermQuery()
        {
            Field = "OrderId",
            Value = "1"
        };
```

to...

```
 QueryContainer query = new TermQuery()
        {
            Field = "OrderId",
            Value = "1"
        };
```

It wont give any output is Test method ELK_algorithmsTests.TestIndexCreation.testToMakeSameSelectionButWithSelectedEvent threw exception:
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: ..

any suggestion where is should look? because im out of ideas right now..

Comment: Please edit your question, or open a new one with the contents of this answer. Opening another question as an answer makes it difficult for people to engage with your questions, which usually means they won't :)